# Android: what mime type which refer to all document

Tags: android, xamarin, mime-types, document

In iOS, I referred the document types with public.data when dealing with document picker. On android, I have to specify an intent filter with DataMimeType with image/* but not sure what mime type for all documents.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support every type of file, you use the `*/*` mime type.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the OS try to determine the appropriate mime type for a file:

String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url));